# How do I run methods on respond_with json data in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I had a model which returns some parameters and includes parameters from other models as follows:

```
def as_json(options = {})
  camelize_keys(super(options.merge(:only => [:id, :userId], include:{ 
    comments: { only: [:test, :id] },
    valediction: { only: [:name, :text, :hidden, :order] }
  })))
end

def camelize_keys(hash)
  values = hash.map do |key, value|
    [key.camelize(:lower), value]
  end
  Hash[values]
end
```

Now I have moved the code to my controller because different controller actions need to return different parts of the model. (index should just return valediction, but show should return comments and valediction)

The new controller:

```
  def index
    respond_with(displayed_user.microposts.all, include: {
      valediction: { only: [:name, :text] }
    })
  end

  def show
    respond_with(displayed_user.microposts.find(params[:id]), include: {
      comments: { only: [:test, :id] },
      valediction: { only: [:name, :text, :hidden, :order] }
    })
  end
```

But I'm very new to rails and I don't know how to put the camelize_keys function in so that it works.

Comment: Why do you even want camelized keys in your JSON output? I get that javascript uses camelcase for function names but a Rails API or any other API that gives camelized attribute names is just weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing complex JSON formatting in your controllers / and or models usually leads to bloat and is a pain to test.

A good solution for this is using the [ActiveModel::Serializer](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers) (AMS) gem. Its included in Rails 5 but you can easily add it to a Rails 4 project by adding it to the gemfile:

```
# See rubygems.org for latest verstion!
gem 'active_model_serializers', '~> 0.9.3'
```

Then run `bundle install` and restart your rails server.

With AMS you create serializer classes which define how your model data should be represented in JSON, XML etc. A serializer is basically a class that takes a model instance (or an array of models) and returns a hash (or an array of hashes) when you call `.serializable_hash`.

But Rails will take care of that part automatically for you.

```
class MicropostSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :user_id
  has_many :comments
  has_many :valedictions
end

class CommentSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :test, :id
end

class ValedictionSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :name, :text, :hidden, :order
end
```

In your controller you can simply call:

```
def index
  render json: displayed_user.microposts.all
end
```

#### But wait, what about `camelize_keys`?

Unless you have to support some weird legacy client that needs camelized keys there are very few reasons to do this. Most large API's use snakecase (Facebook, Google etc.) and Rails 5 is moving towards the JSONAPI spec which uses snakecase.

From your code sample it seems that some of your rails model attributes (and the db columns backing them) use camelcase. You should change the DB column with a migration as soon as possible.

If you HAVE to support a legacy database you can use alias_attribute:

```
class Pet < ActiveRecord::Base
  alias_attribute :ownerId, :owner_id
end
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the detailed answer! I have updated the question slightly since I realize that I was a little unclear... I'm still not sure how I can use your suggestion to make the microposts controller index action return just the microposts attributes and valediction without also returning comments (I still need comments to be returned in the microposts controller show action).

Comment: `render json: displayed_user.microposts.all, except: [:comments]`

Comment: Or you can create different serializers and specify which one to use: `render json: displayed_user.microposts.all, each_serializer: MicropostPreviewSerializer`

Comment: The latter being preferred if you have major differences in the JSON representation so that you don't clutter up your controller.

Comment: You said that I shouldn't need to camelize_keys when retrieving json. So I have implemented this and my JSON now has snake_case keys, but for use in JS, do you mean I should write a function in JS to convert to camelCase? I can't use snake_case in the front end.

Comment: I was saying that you should'nt make your API have camelized keys. Why can't you use snake case in JS?

Comment: Because it would mean updating the names of about a thousand variables. I've also never seen any JS libraries that use snake case, so I'd have to have mixed variable naming which isn't neat.

Comment: There are several JS libraries like ember.js which have adapters for JSON api. Also for example take the facebook JS sdk.

Answer (score 0):

You could move the method to a class method in the model, eg

```
#class methods
class << self
  def camelize_keys(hash)
    values = hash.map do |key, value|
      [key.camelize(:lower), value]
    end
    Hash[values]
  end
end
```

Now you can call this from anywhere like

```
MyModel.camelize_keys(some_hash)
```